# Selecting a specific piece of information using PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, image

I'm looking to create a portfolio using a Wordpress blog. On the summary page for the "blog posts" I want there to be thumbnails of images, and then obviously when you click into these they will go to the full listing for that project.

I figure that I could restrict the posts on the summary page, just to show one image from the description.

My idea is as follows:

```
Post name: Project

Description: <img class="thumbnail-image" /> <img /> <img /> <img /> <p></p>
```

On the summary page I would like the loop just to target and display the image with the class of "thumbnail-image" in each post, and then in the single post page I will hide the thumbnail image using CSS.

What I would like to know is whether there is a good way in php of detecting that first image element from the description and extracting it from the description so that I can display it on the summary page?

Comment: Can you give a better example of how you have the items placed in the description row?

Comment: I thought this was pretty clear but I edited the code block to show html (though rough).

Comment: Why not place something between them than as a separator instead of a space, an use the explode function like `$imgs = explode(";", $row['desc'])` and than use `$imgs[0]` to call for just the first one, which would be the thumbnail.

Comment: Would you be able to suggest an element in particular, or does it just need to be different from an img tag? I apologise, I lack full knowledge of how the explode function works exactly...

Comment: In fact, I have got the function working, but I am unable to inject the contents of `the_content` (the blogs main body) into `$thumbnails` (the array I have ready for the seperated content).

Prior to the explode function I have

`$description = the_content();`

But when I include `the_content()` within the code it publishes the content as is... is there a special way in which I need to define `$description` so it's value will mirror the value of `the_content`?

Comment: If you can paste the code you have, it will be easier to help with. Just going off an explanation of what's happening won't make it feasible to determine where your problem is.

Comment: Ok, the code I have is as follows: `$thumbnailsfull = the_content();`  `$thumbnail = explode("<br />", $thumbnailsfull)` ... (where each image is seperated by a <br /> ... I understand that I would display the first thumbnail by putting `echo thumbnail[0];` however the presence of `the_content()` publishes the content as is,  as if the explode function hasn't had a chance to work...

Comment: Calling `the_content()` won't show anything exploded, it will be as it is in the database if assuming you are using `the_content()` to pull a request from your database. But for one, if you are not using `$thumbnailsfull` for nothing but to call the function `the_content()` than it isn't needed. `$thumbnail = explode("<br />", the_content());` would do the job as far as that. `the_content()` wouldn't display anything that is exploded, if you are want it to display a each individual item that you will want to run `$thumbnail` through a `foreach` statement.

Comment: But what I was attempting to do was that within the `foreach` loop I define that `$thumbnailsfull` is equal to the value of `the_content()`, and then the explode function would be used on `$thumbnailsfull` to output each image to `$thumbnail`... running `$thumbnail` through a `foreach` statement would surely do nothing since it is not part of a series of values...

Comment: (The problem I'm encountering is that whenever I mention `the_content()` it displays the content as is, ie. it doesn't allow me to do anything with the value of `the_content()` - the mere mention of `the_content()` displays the value contained therein.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out in the end:

```
$thumbnail = explode("<br/>", $post->post_content);
echo $thumbnail[0];
```

In my limited knowledge of PHP (learned over the last few days) it seems that `the_content()` is used more to PUBLISH the value of the post's content and any mention of `the_content()` in the code will publish the content contained therein. To target and play with the value further you have to be more specific, ie `$post->post_content` (targetting the post content of the post).